# Use jest-mock-extended and Spectator for angular components testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, angular-spectator, spectator

I'm already using successfully using [jest-mock-extended](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-extended) to test services and it works fine for me. It's simple, easy to use and type safe.

Now I have to test Angular components. For this purpose I've found [Spectator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/spectator). I managed to write tests for simple components without services using the `SpectatorHost` feature. Now I've to test a component with a service that I should mock but I'm really finding hard time to do it.

For this reason I was wondering if there's a way to inject the mock created with `jest-mock-extended` into the component generated inside with `SpectatorHost`.

In this way I would also use the same library to mock the services in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to integrate the two libraries:

```
   describe('MyComponent', () => {
      // SpectatorHost object and factory
      let host: SpectatorHost<MyComponent>;
      const createHost = createHostFactory({
         component: MyComponent,
         mocks: [MyService], // Automatically mock service used by the component
      });

      // MockProxy object from jest-mock-extended
      let myServiceMock: MockProxy<MyService>;

      // Init and reset service before each test
      beforeEach(() => {
         myServiceMock = mock<MyService>();
         
         mockReset(MyService);
      });

      it('...', () => {
         // Mock whatever function in the service
         myServiceMock.doSomething.mockReturnValue('Mock');
         host = createHost('<my-component></my-component>', {
            providers: [{ provide: MyService, useValue: myServiceMock }] // Pass mocked service to the component
         });

         // Rest of the test...         
    });
```